# NTFS with UserMapping under Debian (LMDE 5)

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, ntfs

I've a dual boot system with Windows 10 and LMDE 5.
I'd like to setup file permissions correctly when mounting windows NTFS partitions.

The `.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` was created correctly.

When using `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt/daten` the permissions look like expected. The windows files are shown with my Linux user name.
I'm also able to change permissions e.g. `chmod 600 filename` works as expected. The permissions are changed and the change is still there after reboot and manual remount.

I also checked https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ntfs-3g/mount.ntfs-3g.8.en.html and set up my `/etc/fstab` this way:

```
# /media/windows was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=32FEC511FEC4CE73                           /mnt/windows    ntfs-3g inherit,windows_names   0       0
# /media/daten was on /dev/nvme1n1p5 during installation
UUID=2A904ACB904A9D67                           /mnt/daten      ntfs-3g inherit,windows_names   0       0
```

It again looks normal. The shown user is my Linux user. I can create new files.

**But chmod is not working.** It has simply no effect.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: NTFS permissions are vastly different from Linux. What do you expect `chmod` to do?

Comment: It changes the permissions and we don't need to discuss this, because it works. It works with Debian and manual mount. It works with Ubuntu (manual and fstab). So it's not a matter how it works... it works. The question is, why not when using fstab

Comment: I have an intermediate solution where I mounted manually and set the desired permissions, but an explanation and a solution would be great